# Perl method to create an error object using bless. Not sure about the inner-workings of this method

Tags: perl, object

I received a solution for creating an object which is a hash with 5 keys. But I am not sure how it exactly works.

This is my example of the error library, I only included one error for the purpose of this question.
ErrorLibrary.pm

```
package ASC::Builder::ErrorLibrary;
    use constant {

        CABLING_ERROR => {
            code => 561,
            message => "cabling is not correct at T1.",
            tt => { template => 'disabled'},
            fatal => 1,
            wiki_page =>'http://www.e-solution.com/index.php/ARC/Builder/ErrorCodes/CABLING_ERROR',
        }
    };
```

This is my error file which contains a number of methods; the new() that is use for posting an error. 
The new method can accept the Error hash which are found in the ErrorLibrary or else it can accept a string which is the old way in which the error message were implemented in the system.

Example:

```
die ASC::Builder::Error->new(CABLING_ERROR);
```

Error.pm

```
package ASC::Builder::Error;
    sub new {

        my ($package, $first_param) = (shift, shift);


        if (ref $first_param eq 'HASH') {
            my %params = @_;
            return bless { message => $first_param->{message}, code => $first_param->{code}, tt => $first_param->{tt}, fatal => $first_param->{fatal}, wiki_page => $first_param->{wiki_page}, %params}, $package;
        }
        else {
            my %params = @_; 
            return bless {message => $first_param, %params}, $package;

    }   
    }
```

What I want to understand about this new() method is what exactly is happening when I assign each key of the error hash to `$first_param` an then bless all them. Is it gathering all the attributes together and creating an object out of the attributes by using the bless function?

The Error.pm also contains the following methods which allow the value of each key to be accessed.

```
package ASC::Builder::Error;
    sub message {
        return $_[0]->{message};
    }

    sub tt {
        return $_[0]->{tt};
    }

    sub code {
        return $_[0]->{code};
    }

    sub fatal {
        return $_[0]->{fatal};
    }

    sub wiki_page {
        return $_[0]->{wiki_page};
    }
```

But as I said I mainly just want to understand what is exactly happening in the new() method.

Comment: You keep posting the same unindented code. **Please** indent it properly. Not only here, but also in your files. It will make things so much easier for you. And feel free to accept correct answers on your other questions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Perl, objects are just regular data structures that have been `bless`ed. This is explained in [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#An-Object-is-Simply-a-Data-Structure):

> Objects are merely Perl data structures (hashes, arrays, scalars, filehandles, etc.) that have been explicitly associated with a particular class.
>
> That explicit association is created by the built-in `bless` function, which is typically used within the constructor subroutine of the class.

When you call

```
bless { foo => 'bar' }, $class;
```

in a constructor, you

1. create a reference to an anonymous hash
2. convert the hash reference to an object by passing it to `bless`

The above can be rewritten as follows, which makes it clearer that objects are just regular Perl data structures under the hood:

```
my $self = { foo => 'bar' }; # create a hash reference
bless $self, $class;         # convert the hash reference to an object
```

You can add as few or as many keys to this hash as you want. It's convenient to use hash keys as [attributes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Attributes) or properties that describe an object:

```
my $self = {
    height => 'tall',
    color  => 'purple',
    weight => 17
};
bless $self, $class; # object has three attributes
```

In your code:

```
return bless {
    message   => $first_param->{message},
    code      => $first_param->{code},
    tt        => $first_param->{tt},
    fatal     => $first_param->{fatal},
    wiki_page => $first_param->{wiki_page},
    %params
}, $package;
```

you create a reference to an anonymous hash with at least five keys (more if `%params` is not empty); you then convert the hashref to an object. You can think of `message`, `code`, `tt`, `fatal`, and `wiki_page` as being attributes of the object.

Comment: Ah yes , This is what I was thinking, you made a lot clearer though thanks.